# Getting RuntimeNullPointerException

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-authentication, addeventlistener

Unfortunately, App has stopped

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$AuthStateListener.onAuthStateChanged(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)'
>   on a null object reference

I am beginner.

Here is My Class file

```
package com.example.nagesh.newapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText e1,e2;
private Button button, butn;
public Firebase data;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    e1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.unmae);
    e2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pswd);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    butn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);



    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Info.class);
                          startActivity(i);

            }
        }
    };

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

            startSignin();

        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent o = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
            startActivity(o);

        }
    });



}




@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

private void startSignin()
{

    String email = e1.getText().toString();
    String password = e2.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
    {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Feel All The Fields ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    else {

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
            {

                if (!task.isSuccessful())
                {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"plz check once again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });


    }



}
}
```

What Should I do?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: When error is thrown? On button click, on activity close, etc.?

Comment: And I would suggest you to use FirebaseUI - Auth, there is no point in messing with such things manually https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth/

Comment: When My App goes to this activity, it crashes even before opening of this activity

Comment: Have you added google-services.json?

Comment: What is the error that you get?